# Get attribute values matching xpath

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-console

Consider the following sample HTML:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a href="link1.html">link1</a>
        <a href="link2.html">link2</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

`$x('/html/body/a/@href')` in the Chrome developer console gives me two results:
[image]

Now instead of just matching `href`, I want to extract the attribute values of `href`, so the result I want is an array `["link1.html", "link2.html"]`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get an attribute's value directly using `xPath`, you'll need, after getting the `href`, to loop over them to get each value

```
$x('/html/body/a/@href')[0].value
$x('/html/body/a/@href')[1].value
```

Something like this :

```
$x('/html/body/a/@href').map(x => x.value)
```