# Attributes via XPath in OpenRPA

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, attributes, rpa

In OpenRPA, how to obtain the `@onclick` attributes with XPath?

I'm using the "Get Element" activity.
When `XPath = "//a"`, I can get the texts of all the links, but when `XPath = "//a/@onclick"`, OpenRPA can't find a single link.

Answer (score 1):

`//a/@onclick` selects the `attribute` `@onclick` instead of the `a`-`element`.

You need a [predicate](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/xpath_predicate.htm) on `a` with that `@onclick` to filter those `a`-`elements` that have a `@onclick`-`attribute` like this:

```
XPath = "//a[@onclick]
```

Comment: I just tried, but it didn't work. Still link texts were returned. From what I understand, things inside square brackets are conditions, so you are saying: return all links, whose onclick attributes are not null. But I want the attributes per se. Or do you have a follow-up step to extract the onclick attributes?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63325027/3710053

Comment: But that's not OpenRPA!